# Is it possible to apply one expression for multiple directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a simple code, where I tried to implement what I'm talking about:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example32-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
  <form name='AlertForm' ng-init="action = 'AlertForm.$valid && print(text)'">
    Input: <input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-keyup='$event.keyCode == 13 && {{action}}' /><br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="{{ action }}" value="Alert" />
  </form>

</div>

<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.print = function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
      };

    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/M7hfHytCzqrOMMLSpbZm?p=preview

There is a form with a single input and a button. If you press the button or press enter, while staying in the input, it will alert you with content of the input.

I've tried to use `ng-init` and Angular templating for caching the `print(text)` expression, to avoid redundancy, but it doesn't work.

Is there any other ways, to do that without touching controller?

Comment: Why are you wanting to avoid controllers? What is your goal?

Comment: @AnidMonsur I don't want to have references to forms in my controllers.